# How to ensure the selected file count to be either zero or one using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

In my application I have edit button in gridview where user will click edit button and when he clicks edit button 
all the data related to that particular edited row gets binded to corresponding textboxes and fileupload controls 
at this case user may select another file or he may not select another file if selected the count of the files should not be 
greater than one or zero how can i do this
Below is my fileupload contol,update button and edit image code

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filuploadmp3" runat="server" Width="224px" multiple="multiple" onchange="javascript:return checkwavextension();"  />
<asp:Button ID="btnupdate" runat="server" OnClick="btnupdate_Click" Text="Update" Width="62px" OnClientClick="return validateStuff();" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="Btn1" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="mybutton" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/images/page_white_edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow only one file to select then remove  multiple="multiple"  from FileUpload

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filuploadmp3" runat="server" Width="224px"  onchange="javascript:return checkwavextension();"  />
```

Or if you want to have this then you can check count like

```
function ValidateFile(){
    var fileCount = document.getElementById('filuploadmp3').files.length;
    if(fileCount > 1) // Selected images with in 1count
    {
       alert("Please select only 1!!");
       return false;
    }
    else if(fileCount <= 0) // Selected atleast 1 
    {
       alert("Please select atleat 1!!");
       return false;
    }

    return true;  // Good to go
}





function checkwavextension() {
    var chkFile = document.getElementById('<%= filuploadmp3.ClientID %>');
    var label = document.getElementById('<%= lblerrmsg.ClientID%>');
    var myfile = chkFile.value;
    if (myfile.indexOf(".wav") > 0 || myfile.indexOf(".mp3") > 0) {
        label.innerText = "Valid Format";
      //check mode insert or update
      //if update then 
      return ValidateFile();
    } else {
        label.innerText = "Invalid Format";
        chkFile.value = "";
    }
}

function ValidateFile(){
    var fileCount = document.getElementById('filuploadmp3').files.length;
    if(fileCount > 1) // Selected images with in 1count
    {
       alert("Please select only 1!!");
       return false;
    }
    else if(fileCount <= 0) // Selected atleast 1 
    {
       alert("Please select atleat 1!!");
       return false;
    }

    return true;  // Good to go
}
```

Comment: but already i have javascript method in my update button <asp:Button ID="btnupdate" runat="server" OnClick="btnupdate_Click" Text="Update" Width="62px" OnClientClick="return validateStuff();" /> how can i include anothjer client click event to it moreover i cannot remove multiple while inserting i need multiple but while updating i may have eith one or zero files

Comment: call file length validation on change of fileupload control inside this function checkwavextension

Comment: function checkwavextension(){ //your extension validation login  return ValidateFile(); }

Comment: function checkwavextension() {
            var chkFile = document.getElementById('<%= filuploadmp3.ClientID %>');
            var label = document.getElementById('<%= lblerrmsg.ClientID%>');
            var myfile = chkFile.value;

            if (myfile.indexOf(".wav") > 0 || myfile.indexOf(".mp3") > 0) {
                label.innerText = "Valid Format";
            }
            else {
                label.innerText = "Invalid Format";
                chkFile.value = "";
            }
        } this is my checkwavextension what should i do here

Comment: hi yogesh you din't got my point while adding i may have any no of files but while updating i should contain no file or 1 file but not more than one file this should be check only when i click update button

Comment: You will know the mode like insert or update then based on that decide  to validate with this function or not please check updated function in asnwer

Comment: where have you called ValidateFile() how it will validate only while updating